# OneNote synchronisation phone <-> computer

Tags: windows-8, sync, microsoft-onenote, windows-phone, microsoft-onenote-2013

I have OneNote installed on my HTC8S and on my laptop with Windows 8. In both I'm logged into the same account (my personal outlook.com account) and I want to synchronize my notes between them. I tried numerous methods and looked through the Web, without success. Does anyone have a solution or maybe a how-to/tutorial like description how to setup this synchronization?

Comment: I sync my OneNote by saving the file on my SkyDrive that is linked to my Microsoft account. I don't use Outlook.com, but if you use your MS account to login, you should have SkyDrive (you get 7GB free with an MS account. I sync between 3 devices with no issues.

Comment: I'm using SkyDrive for my pictures and music but didn't know I can use it to synchronise my OneNote notes. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

When you set up a "Microsoft Account" for Windows 8, it is actually a live.com account AKA outlook.com AKA onenote.com AKA OneDrive !! OneDrive is the latest name.

So you just need to make sure that your mobile device uses the same account. When you create a new notebook, make sure you are creating it on your OneDrive (AKA onenote.com) and have the same notebook open on both devices, they will Sync automatically.

Using this method I have a notebook that I use across 3 or 4 laptops, 2 iPhones and an iPad!